# ajuda em request

Tags: python, aplicação-web, request

eu estou escrevendo um scan de subdomain e fiz o seguinte codigo (me desculpe por fazer vcs chorarem com tal):

```
import requests
while True:
 url = raw_input("url: ")
 lista = ['blog', 'ftp', 'cpanel', 'intranet']
 for list in lista:
     url2 = url.replace("www", list)
     req = requests.get(url2)
     if req == True:
        print ("Ok " + url2)
     else:
        print ("Nop" + url2)
```

Poderiam me dizer onde esta o erro e como concerta-lo? Obrigado

Comment: Qual é exatamente o problema? Não funciona? Dá erro? O que acontece se rodar o programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando seu código, me parece que você quer algo assim:

```
import requests
while True:
    url = input("url: ")
    lista = ['blog', 'ftp', 'cpanel', 'intranet']
    for list in lista:
        url2 = url.replace("www", list)
        try:
            req = requests.get('http://{}'.format(url2))
        except:
            print("Erro", url2)
            continue
        if req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            print("Ok", url2)
        else:
            print("NOK", url2)
```

Onde as alterações que fiz foram:

- Adicionar "**http://**" ao request
- Adicionar uma estrutura "**try except**" para capturar erros de conexão (domínio não encontrado, por exemplo)
- Utilizar o **status_code** no teste de sucesso de requisição, onde, a grosso mode, a falha não significa domínio não encontrado, mas sim algo como página não encontrada.